# Having problems detecting keypress in c++

Tags: c++, key, keypress

I am trying to make a simple game in c++ and for this i have to detect keypress (specefically interested in up, down, left and right).  To achieve that, i did the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using string = std::string;

const int K_UP = 72;
const int K_DOWN = 80;
const int K_LEFT = 75;
const int K_RIGHT = 77;

string get_pressed()
{
    if (K_UP == _getch());
    {
        return "UP";
    }
    if (K_DOWN == _getch());
    {
        return "DOWN";
    }
    if (K_RIGHT == _getch());
    {
        return "RIGTH";
    }
    return "LEFT";

}

int main()
{
    cout << "MOVING" << get_pressed() << endl;
}
```

However, whatever i press, the output is "MOVING UP". Also, when i was reading on "how to detect keypresses", i read that 72 is the number given by windows for up-key, but when i try to print `_getch()`
and press the up-key, it gives me 244 and it does the same for rigth, left and down as well. I am confused as to whats going on here and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure its the c++ that came with visual studio

Comment: Just googled what turbo c++ is and its definately not that

Comment: @TedLyngmo Microsoft have declared all the unix API as non-standard, declared new versions with the _ prefix, and called that standard.

Comment: @GemTaylor Posix is not C++ standard either, that's correct. :-)

Comment: Calling _getch 3 times takes 3 different key presses.  Call once and save the value in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are (probably) confusing key codes with ascii codes. The c/c++ methods basically only support ascii codes for the keys, whereas the documentation you are reading is for the raw key codes.

There are APIs that can read the raw keycodes on Windows, for example, and you may need to resort to them anyway, otherwise you may find you suffer from buffered-io where keys are not read at all until newline is pressed.

In unix, or terminal emulators, the arrow and edit keys will generate (probably) an escape sequence, a series of ascii codes starting with the code 31, for escape. The termcap library is supposed to help you decode these.